# length of a variable in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix

Grateful if anyone can please let me know what is the total length that a UNIX variable can take.
I have a variable called filelist and I want to save the content like that :

> filelist=path/name path/name  path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name path/name path/name path/name path/name
>   path/name.....infinity

Comment: Which shell? I'm assuming BASH?

Comment: Youd better use a file to store that. Anyway youll have to manage the data. I dont sincerely know but im sure theres a better way of doing that

Comment: ok...I need this because I want to later do scp $filelist  id@remotohost:path

Answer (score 2):

There are two limitations. The first one is inside the shell. I guess that `bash` don't limit a lot its variables, the real limitation being available resources (if `malloc` fails).

The more important one (which is relevant for your `scp $filelist id@remotohost:path` case) is when you use that variable, e.g. to exec some program. Then [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) is called, and it could fail because the overall program arguments takes too much memory. Read the *Limits on size of arguments and environment* section of the man page:

> Limits on size of arguments and environment

```
   Most UNIX implementations impose some limit on the total size of the
   command-line argument (argv) and environment (envp) strings that may
   be passed to a new program.  POSIX.1 allows an implementation to
   advertise this limit using the ARG_MAX constant (either defined in
   <limits.h> or available at run time using the call
   sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX)).
```

In practice that `execve` limit is significant (e.g. 128Kbytes by default). I often compile my own kernel after editing some kernel header file to raise that limit (e.g. to 1Mbyte).

Notice that a variable which is `export`-ed in `bash` gets into the environment (of future forked processes) subject to above limitations.

BTW, you could transfer the files in some other ways (`rsync` or `git` etc...).